# python manage.py makemigrations blog returns no changes detected in app 'blog'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

this is the sublime text editor code in model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_lenght=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_lenght=250)
    content = models.TextField()
    seo_title = models.CharField(max_lenght=250)
    seo_description = models.CharField(max_lenght=160)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts')
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    Created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_lenght=9, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

===>> later after saving in sublime text editor i opened command promt and typed command "python manage.py makemigrations blog"
it returned an error of - No changes detected in app 'blog'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ6qK.png) screenshot of the error

Comment: What were the changes that you made?

Comment: delete the migration file in the blog app and retry it

Comment: `No changes detected in app,` is not an error. It means you haven't changed anything from your last migration.

Comment: What exactly is your question? @MounaDhaouadi made a good point, that is not an error. What did you expect? Before you delete migrations as suggested you might want to find out what the problem is at all.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by removing the entry of the migration from the database so, go the database you are using and there will be an entry in the `django_migrations` table regarding your table remove that entry and run the command again.